# Is there a more pythonic way to find duplicates of folders and return their paths as a list of tuples?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I implemented this to find duplicates within a folder where folder names take on the format: "NAME_(ID)". The program finds duplicates, where NAME is identical and ID is different, and puts them into a list of tuples with the full path for later merging.

While the approach works well (folder count is never >1000), I couldn't help but wonder if there is a more pythonic and possibly faster approach.

```
def getFolderNumber(f_name):
    return f_name.split("_")[-1]


def discoverDuplicates(path):
    '''
    Discovers duplicate folders
    '''
    #Gets the list of folder ID numbers
    folder_nums = [getFolderNumber(f) for f in os.listdir(path)]
    #Gets the list of full folder names
    folders = [f for f in os.listdir(path)]

    #Returns folder ID numbers if there are more than 1 
    dupes = [item for item, count in collections.Counter(folder_nums).items() if count > 1]

    #Gets the indices for the duplicates in folder_nums, which is of equal length and ordering to folders
    f_indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(folder_nums) if x in dupes]

    #Gets all items in folders that match the indices from above. Sorts this list using the ID number
    pre_zip = sorted([folders[x] for x in f_indices],key=lambda x: getFolderNumber(x).lstrip("(").rstrip(")"))

    #Packages together duplicates into a list of lists
    iterator = iter(pre_zip)
    pre_join = list(map(list,zip(iterator,iterator)))

    #Lambda for joining paths
    path_builder = lambda x: os.path.join(path,x)

    #Joins the final paths within each sublist within the final lists of lists
    return [final.append(list(map(path_builder,x))) for x in pre_join]
```

Here is an example of input:

Input: ListOfFolders(List) contains [NAME1_(459),NAME2(459),NameN(ID_N)...]

Output: [('Path/to/NAME1_(459)','Path/to/NAME2_(459'),(DuplicatePair2),...]

Comment: how can two folders in the same folder have the same name? Can you provide an example?

Comment: I expanded the sentence to make this more clear.

Comment: Please add a small example: Input -> desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this do the job ?

```
from collections import defaultdict

def group_duplicates(folders_names):
    dups_dict = defaultdict(list)
    for folder_name in folders_names:
        folder_name_prefix = folder_name.split('_')[:-1]
        dups_dicts[folder_name_prefix].append(folder_name)
    return [tuple(dups) for dups in dups_dict.values()]
```

It can eventually be seen as more 'pythonic' in the sense that it is very simple and straight-forward (*simple is better than complex*).
One could one-line it with some nested comprehensions, but it would eventually become less readable.

As of the speed, it will perform reasonably fast, so as long as it is not the bottleneck of your program, you should not worry too much about it.

Comment: Not quite. I updated my post to provide an example input/output.

Comment: Beyond prepending `path/to/` to all the folder names, what would be the difference ? In your example the `path/to/`  seems to appear out of the blue.